# How to fetch data which is loaded by the ajax (asynchronous) method after the web page has already been loaded using apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets

I have a sheet, where I was trying to fetch the table contents from the site: `https://listentotaxman.com`

Using the following function:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://listentotaxman.com/?year=2021&ingr=35000","table",2)
```

Desired Output:

[image]

But; no matter what I did, it was not pulling the contents of the table; instead, it just fetched the default table headers and values; not the actual data based on the entered salary which is 35000 in our example. Reason being that the table data on the site is being loaded after the page has already been loaded. Is there a way to accomplish this web scraping using an apps script function? Please help, thank you.

Comment: You would need the help of a service, such as phantomjscloud, which render the javascript for you.

Comment: Can you provide the values you want to retrieve?

Comment: @tanaike yes. let me add the screenshot of the desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the table shown in your question.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

When I tested your URL, unfortunately, it seems that the table cannot be directly retrieved from the URL. So as a workaround, how about retrieving the data from the server and creating a table by parsing the data? When this is reflected in a Google Apps Script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor and save the script. And, please put a custom formula of `=SAMPLE(35000, 2021)` to a cell. By this, the values are retrieved and put to Spreadsheet.

```js
function SAMPLE(grosswage, year) {
  // 1. Retrieve values.
  const url = "https://listentotaxman.com/ws/tax/index.js.php";
  const payload = { "response": "json", "year": year, "region": "uk", "married": false, "blind": false, "exni": false, "marriageallowance": false, "partnerwage": 0, "plan": "", "age": "0", "extra": 0, "taxcode": "", "pension": "", "time": "1", "grosswage": grosswage.toString(), "ingr": "35000" };
  const params = { method: "post", payload: JSON.stringify(payload), contentType: "application/json" };
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);

  // 2. Parse values and create a table.
  const obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  const headers = ["gross_pay", "tax_free_allowance", "taxable_pay", "tax_paid", "tax_due", "student_loan_repayment", "national_insurance", "total_deductions", "net_pay", "employers_ni", "net_change_from_previous"];
  const base = headers.flatMap(h => {
    const temp = [];
    const v = obj[h];
    if (h == "tax_due") {
      Array(3).fill("").forEach((_, i) => temp.push(v[i].amount))
    } else if (h == "total_deductions") {
      temp.push(obj["tax_paid"] + obj["national_insurance"]);
    } else if (h == "net_change_from_previous") {
      temp.push(obj["net_pay"] - obj["previous"]["net_pay"]);
    } else {
      temp.push(v);
    }
    return temp;
  });

  // 3. Return the parsed values as 2 dimensional array.
  const colHead = ["Pay Summary", "%", "Yearly", "Monthly", "Week"];
  const rowHead = ["Gross Pay", "Tax free allowance", "Total taxable", " Total Tax due", "20% rate", "40% rate", "45% rate", "Student Loan", "National Insurance", "Total Deductions", "Net Wage", "Employers NI", "Net change from 2020"];
  return [colHead, ...base.map((e, i, a) => [(e / grosswage) * 100, e, e / 12, e / 52].map((f, j) => i == a.length - 1 && j != 0 ? -Math.floor(f) : Math.floor(f))).map((e, i) => [rowHead[i], ...e])];
}
```

#### Result:

When this script is used, the following result is obtained. About the number format for each column, please set them.

[image]

#### Note:

- This is a simple sample script. So please modify this for your actual situation.
- **I tested only `=SAMPLE(35000, 2021)`. So when other parameters are used, an error might occur. This sample script is for just your this question. So please be careful about this. And also, when the site cannot be used, the values cannot be retrieved. Also, please be careful this.**

Comment: Hi Tanaike, I needed your help again. The script was working fine till now. But, now it is giving the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'amount' of undefined (line 28). Can you please help, thank you.

Comment: @Jack Yuan From your error message, in that case, it is considered that the specification of the site was changed. In this case, can you post it as a new question? Because in this case, it is required to analyze the site again. When you post it as a new question, it will help users including me think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: thanks, I have figured it out. The site is only allowing to pass 2021 as the tax year. I was passing 2022; therefore, it was not working. P.S. Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: @Jack Yuan Thank you for replying. I could understand about it.